# Does Python's `in` keyword perform a linear search?

Tags: python, algorithm, keyword

How does Python checks if a given value exists in an iterable using `in` keyword. Does it perform a linear search? Like :

```
def naive(iterable, val):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if iterable[i]==val:
            return True
    return False
```

? Or it has got a different way of doing that. Other than linear search?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python's `in` operator calls the `__contains__` magic function on the container. That is implemented in different ways for different containers.

For `str`ings, `list`s and `tuple`s, it's a linear search (`O(N)`), though since it's implemented in C it will probably be faster than the pure-python one you have in your question.

For a `set`s and `dict`s, it's a hash-table lookup, which is much faster (`O(1)` average case).

Other containers will have different performance characteristics. I don't think there are any in the standard library, but a balanced tree data structure would probably be `O(log N)`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the possibility of a balanced tree implementing log-time `__contains__`. It's also worth mentioning that it falls back to a linear search if there *isn't* an `__contains__` and that this uses the iterator protocol - meaning, among other things, it works for generators, too.

Answer (score 8):

The `in` keyword depends on the implementation of the `__contains__` method in the object's class you are calling. That means for anything that isn't hashable (list, string) it performs a linear search but for a hashable data structures (dict, set) it would be amortized constant time.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a *linear* data structure yes, it's a linear search. Examples: a list, a string. If it's a set it's an `O(1)` operation, or if we're checking if a key is in a dict is also `O(1)`.